# Inserting json data into html page in list

Tags: php, mysql, json, html

I'm trying to get information from mysql and post the information into an html page. Here's what I've got so far:This is my `tenantlistmob.php`

```
  <?php 
  include('connection.php');
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tenanttemp");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
   $array[] = array($row['TenantFirstName']);
  }
echo json_encode($array);
 ?>
```

When i call `tenantlistmob` from browser directly it shows `[["Humayun"],["Sahjahan"],["Bayezid"],["Bayezid"],["Asaduzzaman"],["Mouri"]]` where firstnames are comming. I like to use this name in html page. my html page is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<body>
 <div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>
<script id="source" type="text/javascript">
 $(function () 
 {
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'tenantlistmob.php',                
  data: "",                        
  dataType: 'json',                 
  success: function(data)          
  {
    var id = data;              
   //var vname = data[1];           //get name
    $.each(id, function (val)
   {        
     $('#output').html(""+id);
    });
  } 
});
}); 

</script>
<form id="formset">
<fieldset id="fieldset">
<h3 align="center">Tenant List</h3><hr/>
<a href="#">name1</a><br /><hr/>
<a href="#">name2 </a> <br /><hr/>
</fieldset>
</form>
<a id="box-link1" class="myButtonLink"  href="category1.php"></a> 
</div>    
 </body>
</html>
```

My output(`main.css`) is like this

```
#output
{
color:#ffffff;
font-size : 20px;
margin : 0;
letter-spacing:1px;
width:480px;
}
```

I am getting the first name as`Humayun,Sahjahan,Bayezid,Bayezid,Asaduzzaman,Mouri` in top-left corner. But i like to get the name as list(`name1`,`name2`) with link. when i click on a name(`name1`,`name2`) it will show details of the name. How can I do this?

Thank in advance

Comment: Please don't laugh if I ask this: You know that you could directly generate the HTML from the PHP script without the ajax request in between? Also if you like to use ajax, you might want to use some template so you only need to fill the values in.

Comment: As an aside, in your `DOCTYPE`, `html` should be lower case.  Also, the `language` attribute for `script` elements is deprecated in HTML 5.  Also, never use the `align` attribute.  It has been deprecated for years.  Use CSS to center elements on a page.  Finally, your `a` elements are not closed properly, i.e. `<a href="addtenant.html" </a>` should be `<a href="addtenant.html">Add Tenant</a>`

Comment: @hakre I am using ajax because this html page is called by android device via phonegap. --"Micah Henning" Thank you very much,but how can i get the data in html page in href link.

Comment: A javascript based template library is [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) - it works very well with json.

Comment: @hakre Thank you very much.It is interesting but i have little time to show this task.can u help me how can i show the data in html page.Please.

Comment: Just output it. If you only have the time to copy and paste code, I don't have any time either. Good bye.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your looking to iterate the JSON using JavaScript. Since you're using jQuery, you simply need to "iterate" the JSON result. Technically 0 comes before 1 in JavaScript.

```
var _result = $data[0];
$.each(_result, function (val)
{
    console.log(val);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Lol your comment reminded me of clipy the paper clip from early microsoft word, "it looks like you..." +1 for a link to the api

Comment: Lol never even thought about the fact that clippy began his sentences with that. (Note to self: never start a sentence with "It looks like..."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
  include('connection.php');
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tenanttemp");

  $array = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {
     $array[] = $row['TenantFirstName'];
   }
  echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: It is better but not my solution.I like to get data in html page as list with anchor tag.